# Vscode mutli line cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode, when you press the right mouse button once and start traversing, a cursor will appear for each line.

**How to disable it?**

[image]

Comment: To be precise, in the language of VSCode's settings it is not called multi line cursor,but instead called column(box) selection, somewhat similar in functionality but a different setting. Knowing the exact term helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `Column Selection Mode`.

View/Selection/Column Selection Mode : make sure it is unchecked.